# Code Execution Sequence

Tags: vb.net, plc

I am a PLC programmer who is currently using a variant of VB to control a motor.

I want to call a function that will execute moves and not return to the main code until the move has been completed. Currently here is what I have:

```
Program  'Main Program
   While 1
      If move_req = 1
         Function MoveMotor
      End If 
   Wend
End Program

Function MoveMotor
   MoveABS 10  ' Move to encoder position 10mm
   move_complete = 1
   While move_req = 1
      'Do Nothing
   Wend
End Function
```

For some reason this code isn't working and the move command is being sent over and over again. Could this be because the main program continues to run when the function is running? Is that how VB works? I am used to thinking of code sequence in terms of PLC's where they scan through everything repeatedly at a certain frequency.

Comment: Program is running due to the While statement. And no where can I see that `move_reg` is changed so the function keeps getting called.

Comment: Its like an infinite loop here.

Comment: Here is what is happening: Program starts, and begins an infinite loop (While 1), first MoveMotor is called, which in turn calls MoveABS. MoveMotor will wait until all code in MoveABS is executed, return to MoveMotor, then start another loop (infinite?) waiting for a variable named move_req to become 1. Question: What changes the value of move_req? In this sample, nothing does, so the program infinitely stays in the While move_req loop.

Comment: The PLC does. Sorry if that wasn't clear. That is part of my handhaking process. PLC sets move_req, controller makes move and sets move_complete, PLC recieves move_complete at which point it turns on move_req. I think the problem is that it takes up to 17ms for the PLC to change that bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the move is complete, there must be a way for it to be detected by the program. It looks like you want move_req to be set to zero when this happens, but I cannot see what would cause that. How does the machine signal the program that it's finished moving?

A second point is that when you have a loop that waits while it checks for variable change, it can cause a CPU spike. You can put a pause in the loop with some thing like `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)` where 100 is milliseconds to pause.